# Ejected into space -- survival tactics

Tags: science, space

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What would really happen if you were exposed to space?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/2628/what-would-really-happen-if-you-were-exposed-to-space)

In several Sci-Fi adventures (e.g.: [2001: A space Oddessy](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0062622/) and [HHGTG](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0345391802)) the protagonist survives a markedly brief stint in the vacuum of space. Often, a character will supply some hints at tactics for surviving just a moment or two longer than perhaps you might otherwise -- "close your eyes," or "hold your breath," -- and perhaps the hero wins the day because of his foresight.

Almost universally, though, the author suggests that holding your breath is a key to survival, which has always struck me as wrong-headed. As a diver, you're taught to *never* hold your breath, especially when ascending, since holding your breath during decompression causes [fatal lung injuries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barotrauma#Pulmonary_barotrauma).

What sort of scientifically-sound tactics could an author recommend to a character about to face a few seconds out in space in order to avoid (or at least delay) death, and perhaps aid recovery if quickly rescued?

Related: http://www.geoffreylandis.com/ebullism.html